# jQuery checkbox validation dosn't work

Tags: jquery

This script is doing checkbox depending on the amount of information collected from xml file

```
 function parseXml(xml) {  
  $(xml).find("sterowniki").each(function() { 
  var i = 1;
$(xml).find("items").each(function() { 
$( "#pierwszy" ).append(' <div class="row"><div class="checkbox"><label><li class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10"><a href="produkt.html?id='+i+'">'+$(this).attr('name')+'</a></li><input class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" type="checkbox" name="porownaj"  value="stery"></label></div></div>');     
  i=i+1;
   });
});
}  
});
```

This is validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var limit = 1;
$('input.checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
   this.checked = false;
}
});
</script>
```

However, the validation does not work. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `input.checkbox` does not match anything in your markup. You want `input[type=checkbox]`, or possibly `div.checkbox input`.

Comment: unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Then the checkboxes are probably added dynamically. Event delegation should be used in that case, see the "Direct and delegated events" section in the documentation for [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are finding checkbox with `class="checkbox"` but actually `div` containing checkbox has this class.

So find `checkbox` inside the `div` to bind change event. And all checkboxes are not siblings so you need to find them inside `div` and then take count.

See below code -

```
var limit = 1;
$('#pierwszy').on('change','div.checkbox input[type=checkbox]', function() {
   var count = $('div.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  if(count > limit) {
   this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer, as pointed by Jai these are dynamic elements and hence cannot bind change event directly but using its ancestor i.e. `pierwszy`

Comment: Also remove `>=` and put only `>` to check two checkbox when `limit=2`

Comment: However, I have another question. Assigned to each checkbox is id. In some way I can check the checkbox with which id is selected? Thanks

Comment: yes you can. see this `$('div.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){ alert($(this).prop('id'));});`

Comment: Alert nothing is displayed or broadcast checbox no id? I do not understand why.

Comment: have you added `id` to the checkboxes?

Comment: i don't have id and i add its work ;) You know how i edit this funcion to get chexbox id? var results = new RegExp('[\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
            return results[1] || 0;

Comment: This function get id retrieves the link. I mus get id checkbox :(

Answer (score 0):

yes that should not work because you are binding the change event on the element which is dynamically generated, at the time of page load your script loaded but dom does not had that checkbox, so you have to delegate the event to the `closest static parent` or to the `document` itself:

```
$('#pierwszy').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(evt) {
```

or:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(evt) {
```

---

Note:-

You are appending some elements which does not have any closing.

Comment: Work! :) Thanks. But i have one more small problem when  var limit = 2; i can check only 1 chcecbox.You know why ?

Comment: This is because you have if condition `>=`, here `=` causing problem so remove it and check. See my updated answer.